# What is the proper config for jest.mock() to work with a webpack alias?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock an ES6 class constructor using jest v23.6.0 and babel 6.22.1.  The actual code is more complicated, obviously, than what's below, but I've stripped it down to just this and still have the issue.

I have the following class:

StageComponent.js

```
export default class StageComponent {
  constructor () {}
}
```

and the following test code:

```
import StageComponent from './StageComponent';
jest.mock('./StageComponent');

describe('StageComponent', () => {
  it('should track constructor', () => {
    let c = new StageComponent();

    expect(StageComponent).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

When I test this, I get

```
 jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function StageComponent]

       6 |     let c = new StageComponent();
       7 |
    >  8 |     expect(StageComponent).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                            ^
       9 |   });
      10 | });
      11 |
```

No matter what I try, it's like the mock() call isn't doing anything.  Jest otherwise seems to be working fine (e.g. I have replaced individual properties with jest.fn() successfully) so I don't think it's my installation.  Is there something I'm missing?  This seems to be straight out of the docs...

**EDIT:** 
The actual code for the test was:

```
import StageComponent from '@/StageComponent';
jest.mock('@/StageComponent');

...
```

and my changing it for simplicity when I posted this obscured the issue, which was the webpack alias `@` in the path.  It works fine if I give it the full path (including the .js at the end) in both the `import` and the `mock()`.  So now the question is why the alias doesn't work. (Also note that using the alias in the `import` and not in the `mock()` produces the same outcome, if that's a clue).

In webpack config I have this `alias`:

```
'@': resolve('src')
```

In jest config I have this `moduleNameMapper`:

```
'^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
```

And in fact if I change the `moduleNameMapper` it throws errors about not finding the file, so I would think if it weren't working at all, it would be throwing similar errors rather than not applying the `mock()`

Comment: Did you create a [Manual Mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) for the `StageComponent` user module?  That is the only thing I can think of that could cause this.  I set up a clean installation and can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors No manual mocks.  I also deleted node_modules and reinstalled everything.  No luck.  Could it be something with my babel or jest config?  I wouldn't think so, because it shouldn't work at all if babel wasn't running (and if I remove the babel-jest transform from the config, it does in fact break completely).  But I can't think of what else it could be.

Comment: Found half the problem - see question edit notes above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running on Windows, the capitalization has to match across all of the `import` statements throughout the code (across all files) and the `mock()` statements.  You'll obviously get an error on other platforms if that's the not case, but on Windows it will successfully load the file with no errors, but the `import` and the `mock` won't line up and thus the mocked constructor doesn't get called.